# Downloading contents of several html pages using python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and was trying to figure out how to code a script that will download the contents of HTML pages. I was thinking of doing something like:

```
Y = 0
X = "example.com/example/" + Y
While Y != 500:
(code to download file), Y++
if Y == 500:
break
```

so the (`Y`) is the file name and I need to download files from `example.com/example/1` all the way till file number `500`, regardless of the file type.

Comment: Very little of your code so far is valid Python - indentation is important, Python doesn't have the `++` increment and you can't concatenate strings and integers, for example. You need to clarify what you're trying to do - download files, scrape HTML, or something else?

Comment: I'm trying to download several files from a website. They are a mix of videos/Audios/pictures/Word files sent to me by my boss. I was learning programming and I asked myself: why not write a code that will download all of the files and hit 2 birds with one stone. I'm using python 3.4

Comment: Perhaps you should take this in smaller steps: 1. How can you download one file, given a URL. 2. How can you create a range of URLs. 3. How can you iterate over 2. and pass them to 1.

Comment: thanks for the tips. I hope they will keep me busy and thinking *brofist*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [official docs page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html):

> This module provides a high-level interface for fetching data across the World Wide Web.
>
> In particular, the `urlopen()` function is similar to the built-in function `open()`, but accepts Universal Resource Locators (URLs) instead of filenames.
>
> Some restrictions apply — it can only open URLs for reading, and no seek operations are available.

So you have code like this:

```
import urllib
content = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()
#urllib.request.urlopen(...).read() in python 3
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe ty :D did not know how to indent the doc like you did.

Comment: No problem - it's the quote (`“`) rather than the braces (`{}`) button in the edit view.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli you can explore the community help to see more formatting syntax. Really interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should meet your need. It will download 500 web contents and save them to disk.

```
import urllib2

def grab_html(url):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    mimetype = response.info().getheader('Content-Type')
    return response.read(), mimetype

for i in range(500):
    filename = str(i)  # Use digit as filename
    url = "http://example.com/example/{0}".format(filename)
    contents, _ = grab_html(url)
    with open(filename, "w") as fp:
        fp.write(contents)
```

Notes:

- If you need parallel fetching, here is a great example https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: This will not work - `TypeError` on the attempts to concatenate `i`, which is an integer, with various strings.

Comment: Wouldn't the `url = "http://example.com/example/" + i` still be concatenating a string and and integer?